# customer save beore process checkout button click

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hello, I want to save a new customer on checkout page after filling their information but before the checkout button clicked. Is there any possibility of creating and saving a new customer in the database by using observers or other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write an observer to get triggered on save shipping events and save the customer.

for example:

create Yournamespace_Yourmodulename.xml in app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
</modules>
```

in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            <observers>
                <auto_register_shipping>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoRegisterBilling</method>
                </auto_register_shipping>
            </observers>
        </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer {

    public function autoRegisterBilling($evt){
        if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            $data = $evt->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
            $email = $data['email'];
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            $pwd = $data['customer_password'];
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);

            if (!$customer->getId()) {
                 //Code begins here for new customer registration
                $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
                $customer->setStore($store);
                $customer->firstname = $data['firstname'];
                $customer->lastname = $data['lastname'];
                $customer->setEmail($email);
                $customer->setPassword($pwd);
                $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');  
                $customer->save();
                   }
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this really work? I discovered, that during checkout everything is put into one big transaction. If you want to threw an exception it is not possible to create an user. The transaction is rolled back. I wrote an external script which gets all user data and runs the user creation code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this observer event **checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method** this event will fire when customer continue from shipping methods .

You can get customer billing/shipping address from quote object.

Comment: i tried this but not getting all details form billing info and i am using one page checkout method

Comment: Ok so edit your post what have you tried and what are you not getting.

Comment: means i am getting NULL from first name ,last name only getting post code and i done want t save NULL value for customer info